# Strange behavior of button onclick

Tags: javascript, html, button

Im currently working on a project and I have some trouble with my navbar.

I have two buttons there in a dropdown:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
   <button class="dropdown-item all" id = "my_all" onclick = "showApplied()">Angemeldet</button>
   <button class="dropdown-item off" id = "empty" onclick = "switchShowAllEmpty()">Leere Aktivitäten einblenden</button>
</div>
```

The second button works fine, but when I click the first one nothing happens. When I change the over button "empty" still is working and button "my_all" not. BUT when I manipulate the copy inside the browser by copying the first button and pasting it in the dropdown again, the pasted one works although the origional didn't.

To my this just makes no sense. And the onclick-function also works fine, so this is not the problem. Please let me know if someone has an idea what's the problem.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in an [mre]. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) to produce a runnable example here on SO.

Comment: The problem is, that if we can't reproduce the issue with the posted code, the question is useless for the future readers after you've fixed the page. That's why we need the code here.

Comment: as in my previous comment: the problem is, when i put the code somethere else like in jsfiddle is works. One more reason why i don't see the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't yet identified the minimal part of the [mre]. Keep adding more code from your project until you start seeing the issue recurring. That's essentially what debugging is; remove things until the problem stops occurring, then re-add things one at a time until you see it come back; then you know what that one thing is that was causing the problem. You might need to do that with smaller and smaller chunks of code over a long period of time. Frustrating sometimes, especially when you got people breathing down your neck, but that's the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code lies at line number #143 inside showAll() function.

```
function showAll(){
        document.getElementById("my_all").onclick = "showApplied()";
```

You are trying to give a string value (which is function text) to onclick property rather than a function definition. You can remove that because anyways you have applied onclick event to the button in HTML.

Anyway if you really want it there then,

You can try `document.getElementById("my_all").onclick = showApplied`

You can refer onclick property docs [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/event_onclick.asp). You can also try an see working example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick_dom).

Comment: oh wow, your right. I'd never thought this would be the problem, thank you so much!